# Rails capistrano-maintenance gem - allow specific urls while maintenancing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rubygems

I am trying to use `capistrano-maintenance` gem and here is an example for nginx config to set mainenance page:

```
error_page 503 @503;

# Return a 503 error if the maintenance page exists.
if (-f /var/www/domain.com/shared/public/system/maintenance.html) {
  return 503;
}

location @503 {
  # Serve static assets if found.
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }

  # Set root to the shared directory.
  root /var/www/domain.com/shared/public;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
}
```

I am looking a way to exclude (allow access as usual) redirecting to maintenance page for specific urls.

For example - I would like to access to sidekiq (https://test.com/sidekiq && https://test.com/sidekiq/*).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solve it by adding

```
...
if ($request_uri ~ /sidekiq(.*)) {
  break;
}
...
```

Before

```
...
if (-f /var/www/domain.com/shared/public/system/maintenance.html) {
...
```